# how can i capture packets from my router to a server

Tags: router, sniffing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I capture packets going from my router to a specific server?](https://superuser.com/questions/453059/how-can-i-capture-packets-going-from-my-router-to-a-specific-server)

I have a small local network in my house that has two computers connected to a modem-router. i would want to capture the packets going from the router to a specific server (i know the ip of the server). the router's manufactor's is d-link
p.s i don't have access to the server.